# Import leaflet with typescript in polymer 3

Tags: node.js, typescript, leaflet, polymer-3.x

I try to build a progressive web app with polymer 3 and typecript and im running into some problems while importing leafelt.
I downloaded the **@types** from leaflet und **leafelt** itself with npm and try to import it like this:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
```

But if i try **polymer serve** the page with leaflet is not loading and i get the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'L' of undefined
    at leaflet-src.js:6
    at leaflet-src.js:7
```

My dependencies in package.json are:

```
"dependencies": {
"@polymer/app-layout": "^3.0.0",
"@polymer/paper-checkbox": "^3.1.0",
"@polymer/polymer": "^3.1.0",
"@types/leaflet": "^1.2.14",
"@vaadin/router": "^1.2.0",
"@vaadin/vaadin-button": "^2.1.1",
"@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.0.0",
"leaflet": "^1.3.4",
"pwa-helpers": "^0.9.0",
"tsd-jsdoc": "^2.0.4"
```

}

Is there a step I'm missing or how can i achieve this in polymer 3 with typescript and use leaflet?

Comment: I think the package is not installed or due to its download instruction, you will need to download the package manually as described here: https://leafletjs.com/download.html then after extracting the files into your project file  you will need to inclued it. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/leaflet.css" />
<script src="/path/to/leaflet.js"></script>`

Comment: @HakanC I tried this but it didnt work. The files get detected and load but in the file leaflet-src.js the error is thrown every time. I tried to include the script in my index.html and in the  "my-app.ts" html template. Both did not work.

Comment: Sorry, the above direction not for Polymer3.  But try import `import 'leaflet';` and 
`import 'leaflet.markercluster';` as normal  than try to use `const L = window['L'];`

Comment: @HakanC I dont manage to bring `const L = window['L'];` to work. It throws the error:  **"Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Window' has no index signature."** I have to use it outside the class correct ?

Comment: Yes, for general use case is like that. You can pass the L value into to Shadow dom(class).

Comment: Here an example of how to pass data into Polymer: https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-bind

Comment: I can compile it with `const L = (window as any)['L'];` but the error is still there :( .